# Remove value from the model for dynamically disabled (via `expressionProperties`) field?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

When an `angular-formly` (I am using v6.4.x w/ AngularJS 1.2.x) field's expression property causes the field to dynamically toggle between enabled and disabled, a switch to disabled does not remove any previously entered value for that field from the model. For example:

1. Using the [advanced layout example from Formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/bootstrap-specific/advanced-layout)
2. Enter a *first name*, such that the *last name* is enabled
3. Enter value for *last name*
4. Remove the *first name* value such that *last name* is again disabled
5. Notice that the model still contains the data entered for *last name* even though it is disabled

Given how `disabled` works for standard HTML form submission, I would expect the model to no longer contain a value for that field.

I need to avoid submitting data for a field that has been disabled, so if this is intended behavior (and I don't *know* that it is...), can someone offer thoughts on how to accomplish the removal of a value whenever `expressionProperties` causes a field to be disabled?

Comment: It's definitely intended behavior, because angular-formly does no more than disable the field using angular's `ng-disabled` which will not clear the model. If you wish to have extra behavior (clear the model) you'll have to do some extra work. `expressionProperties` is probably not the place to do this extra work. You may consider adding a `controller` that has a `$scope.$watch('to.disabled', function() {.. your logic ..})` to respond to the change.

Comment: @kentcdodds, Thanks for your thoughts. I hear you, and agree it is probably intended. It is odd to me that a disabled form element would, by default, be included in the resulting model, but that's fine. I am willing to do the extra work, but I didn't feel like a watch was best. For clarity, though, and in helping me decide, can you explain your watch value, to.disabled? Is to a placeholder for my field name, or does it mean something special in Angular?

Comment: Yeah, it may or may not be the best approach, but it's the approach that angular has taken, and angular-formly doesn't do any extra work to change that. The `to` is a shortcut for `options.templateOptions`. `options` refers to your field's configuration options. It doesn't mean anything special to angular, it's just what is on the `formly-field`'s scope, which is what you get when you add a `controller` to a field and inject the `$scope`

Comment: @kentcdodds Thanks again, you helped me piece together a workable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kentcdodds' comments got me moving in the right direction and able to find enough pieces in the docs to make something work. In my most immediate task I was needing a radio option to get removed from the model when disabled, and I ended up unchecking it too. I did this by extending the `radio` input type and adding a `link` function for access to `scope` and the `element`. Below is something along the lines of what it looks like:

```
app.config(['formlyConfigProvider', function (formlyConfigProvider) {
    formlyConfigProvider.setType({
        name: 'liveDisableRadio',
        extends: 'radio',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('to.disabled', function (is_disabled) {
                if (is_disabled) {
                    delete scope.model[scope.options.key];
                    element.find(':radio:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}])
```